# Partner community Task reports

Tags: reporting, partner-communities

On our partner community the users are not able to see the related to and assigned to fields.

Following below articles I changed org-wide sharing to private for all objects that could be linked to a task to private or disabled "track activities" on the object.

[Relationship Fields not Accessible on reports for Partner Community User](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/140289/relationship-fields-not-accessible-on-reports-for-partner-community-user)

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000004441&type=1

This did not change anything. Fields are still not visible.

FYI: I also checked FLS and the report type: fields are visible AND added to the layout.

Any of you have something I could try?